# Access Spark broadcast variable in different classes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am broadcasting a value in Spark Streaming application . But I am not sure how to access that variable in a different class than the class where it was broadcasted.

My code looks as follows:

```
object AppMain{
  def main(args: Array[String]){
    //...
    val broadcastA = sc.broadcast(a)
    //..
    lines.foreachRDD(rdd => {
    val obj = AppObject1
    rdd.filter(p => obj.apply(p))
    rdd.count
  }
}

object AppObject1: Boolean{
  def apply(str: String){
    AnotherObject.process(str)
  }
}
object AnotherObject{
  // I want to use broadcast variable in this object
  val B = broadcastA.Value // compilation error here
  def process(): Boolean{
   //need to use B inside this method
  }
}
```

Can anyone suggest how to access broadcast variable in this case?

Answer (score 8):

There is nothing particularly Spark specific here ignoring possible serialization issues. If you want to use some object it has to be available in the current scope and you can achieve this the same way as usual:

- you can define your helpers in a scope where broadcast is already defined:

  ```
  {
      ...
      val x = sc.broadcast(1)
      object Foo {
        def foo = x.value
      }
      ...
  }
  ```
- you can use it as a constructor argument:

  ```
  case class Foo(x: org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast[Int]) {
    def foo = x.value
  }

  ...

  Foo(sc.broadcast(1)).foo
  ```
- method argument

  ```
  case class Foo() {
    def foo(x: org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast[Int]) = x.value
  }

  ...

  Foo().foo(sc.broadcast(1))
  ```
- or even mixed-in your helpers like this:

  ```
  trait Foo {
    val x: org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast[Int]
    def foo = x.value
  }

  object Main extends Foo {
    val sc = new SparkContext("local",  "test", new SparkConf())
    val x = sc.broadcast(1)

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      sc.parallelize(Seq(None)).map(_ => foo).first
      sc.stop
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: are there any performance implications in passing broadcast variables around as function parameters (for instance in a curried map function: `map(bcast)(row)`)? The typical Spark example always instantiates a broadcast variable within the same scope of a function using it. What if you'd like to move a map function out of scope but still reference a broadcast variable?

Comment: @zero323 is it a bad idea to pass the broadcast or broadcast value through other methods until it reaches where it is used?  Like if I have a run method I created inside of main that I pass the broadcast.value("foo" in your example) to then eventually to the .flatmap? Is it better to create the broadcast in the driver or can you create it inside the function that is put in a flatmap?

Comment: @zero323, can we pass broadcast variables to UDFs defined as separate classes? If so, how? I'm using Spark with Java, though.

Answer (score 3):

Just a short take on performance considerations that were introduced earlier.

Options proposed by zero233 are indeed very elegant way of doing this kind of things in Scala. At the same time it is important to understand implications of using certain patters in distributed system.

It is not the best idea to use mixin approach / any logic that uses enclosing class state. Whenever you use a state of enclosing class within lambdas Spark will have to serialize outer object. This is not always true but you'd better off writing safer code than one day accidentally blow up the whole cluster.

Being aware of this, I would personally go for explicit argument passing to the methods as this would not result in outer class serialization (`method argument` approach).

Answer (score 1):

you can use classes and pass the broadcast variable to classes

your psudo code should look like :

```
object AppMain{
   def main(args: Array[String]){
     //...
     val broadcastA = sc.broadcast(a)
     //..
     lines.foreach(rdd => {
       val obj = new AppObject1(broadcastA)
       rdd.filter(p => obj.apply(p))
       rdd.count
     })
   }
}

class AppObject1(bc : Broadcast[String]){
   val anotherObject = new AnotherObject(bc)
   def apply(str: String): Boolean ={
      anotherObject.process(str)
   }
}

class AnotherObject(bc : Broadcast[String]){
  // I want to use broadcast variable in this object
  def process(str : String): Boolean = {
    val a = bc.value
    true
    //need to use B inside this method
  }
}
```